Using in-memory dBase III (DBF) databases in Python
I am aware of several Python packages available to read dBase III files (dbf: https://github.com/ethanfurman/dbf/tree/master , dbfpy: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy/files/ , dbfread: https://github.com/olemb/dbfread , simpledbf: https://github.com/rnelsonchem/simpledbf/tree/master ). However, these packages expect to read a file from disk whereas I would like to read an in-memory file (created elsewhere). It is possible with dbf to read a file from disk and to keep it in memory, but this is not what I need, as the dBase file I want to read has been already created in memory, as stated, and has not been written, as such, on disk.
I have installed dbf and dbfread (dbfread seeming rather too old), read the documentation there was and (for dbf and simpledbf) scoured the code, looking for a proper byte, bytearray or io.BytesIO importer or table constructor thereof, but failed. Experimenting by passing these types to the available constructors obviously failed as well… I could certainly write the in-memory file to disk and then read it back in, but that is rather wasteful. Is there a better way, short of re-implementing the needed functionality myself?
Thanks

For dbf, there is no way to read a table from memory -- it only works with on-disk files.
Supporting that is on my to-do list, I just haven't gotten to it yet.

Given that I had a current need to read a dBase III already in memory, using Python (3.12.5), I found a solution by following these steps.

I downloaded the file simpledbf.py from the simpledbf package, copied it my module, and patched it (changes strings containing now-illegal escapes into raw strings).

I coded the following file:
 import struct


 from . import simpledbf


 class from_memory_Table(simpledbf.Dbf5):

     def __init__(self, a_file_name, dump, a_codec = 'utf-8'):

         self._enc = a_codec
         self.dbf = a_file_name
         # Escape quotes, set by indiviual runners
         self._esc = None

         # Reading as binary so bytes will always be returned
         self.f = dump

         self.numrec, self.lenheader = struct.unpack('<xxxxLH22x', self.f.read(32))
         self.numfields = (self.lenheader - 33) // 32

         # The first field is always a one byte deletion flag
         fields = [('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1),]

         for fieldno in range(self.numfields):

             name, typ, size = struct.unpack('<11sc4xB15x', self.f.read(32))

             # eliminate NUL bytes from name string
             name = name.strip(b'\x00')

             fields.append((name.decode(self._enc), typ.decode(self._enc), size))

         self.fields = fields

         # Get the names only for DataFrame generation, skip delete flag
         self.columns = [f[0] for f in self.fields[1:]]

         terminator = self.f.read(1)
         assert terminator == b'\r'

         # Make a format string for extracting the data. In version 5 DBF, all
         # fields are some sort of structured string

         self.fmt = ''.join(['{:d}s'.format(fieldinfo[2]) for fieldinfo in self.fields])
         self.fmtsiz = struct.calcsize(self.fmt)



The a_file_name is arbitrary (but known in my use case) and the dump argument refers to the io.BytesIO object built from the bytearray containing the dBase III table.
The code is essentially a copy of simpledbf.Dbf5.__init__, but with two essential modifications:

I omit the opening of a on-disk file

I assign dump to self.f


As well, I do not call super().__init__.
The package chosen was simplebdf rather than dbf in this case as, though it has less functionality, it is still sufficient for my current need, and its much simpler structure was easier to derive from. As well, it seems to be evolving much more slowly, from what I can see on its repository activity.
